# CSS Invalid Property Value. Assigning class mulitple inheritanes

Tags: html, css

I have a instant messaging light application where 2 users can communicate. I have 2 classes, one for the sender and one for the receiver.

HTML

```
    <div class="textcontainer lighter">
    {{ message }}
    <span class="time-right">{{ message.timestamp }}</span>
</div>  

    {% else %}  
<div class="textcontainer darker">
  <span class="time-left">11:05</span>
```

CSS

```
.textcontainer {
border: 2px solid #dedede;
background-color: #4080ff;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px 0;
}

/* Darker chat textcontainer */
.darker {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: : 0px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.lighter {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: : 100px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Picture 
[image]

What I'm confused about is why the css for .lighter: `margin-left: : 100px;` is not being applied. When I inspect the element. I see that `margin-left` is crossed out.

What is happening here and how can I apply margin left to the 'lighter/green' text box? It may be the `margin` in the .text container is overriding it, but if that was the case, then the `background-color`would also be struck through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking quick it looks like you have some extra semi-colons.  Margin-left should fail on both but you only notice in on the one you want to see move away from the left. Just try removing the extra : on the margin-left style in those classes and it should be good.

```
.darker {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.lighter {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```